# Calculate difference between sum of grouped variable and another variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a data frame like this:

```
example.df <- data.frame(Year = rep(1:3, each = 3),
                         Product = rep(c("bottle_water", "tap_water", "juice"), 3),
                         Product_grouped = rep(c("water", "water", "juice"), 3),
                         Required = c(10, 15, 10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 35, 0),
                         Group_avail = rep(c(25, 25, 10), 3),
                         Purchased = c(0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0))
> example.df
  Year      Product Product_grouped Required Group_avail Purchased
1    1 bottle_water           water       10          25         0
2    1    tap_water           water       15          25         0
3    1        juice           juice       10          10         0
4    2 bottle_water           water       10          25         5
5    2    tap_water           water       20          25         0
6    2        juice           juice       10          10         0
7    3 bottle_water           water       10          25        20
8    3    tap_water           water       35          25         0
9    3        juice           juice        0          10         0
```

Where for each `Year`, I have the `Required` quantities of each `Product`. Two of the products (`tap_water` and `bottled_water`) can be grouped in `water`. In this case, the total quantity available is shown in `Group_avail`.

In years when the total `Required` `Product_grouped` is greater than the `Group_avail`, I want to purchase the difference. However, the difference must be `Purchased` in `bottle_water` only. For example, in `Year` 2, we require 20 `tap_water` and 10 `bottle_water` but there is only a 25 water available, so 5 `bottle_water` is `Purchased`.

I'm looking specifically for a solution suitable for piping.

Thanks!

**Edit**
I've added another `Year` for further clarity on what I want. In any situation where the total `Required` for the `Product_grouped` is surpassed, the difference should always be purchased in `bottle_water`.

Comment: How do you know it is the `bottle_water` that has to be purchased and not the `tap_water`?

Comment: I hope the edit makes it clearer what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for. For your purpose I first modified `Required` column to show the `sum` of every `Product_grouped` and then I check whether the sum in first row of every group surpasses the `Group_avail` or not. In case it does we calculate the difference provided that our first category is always `bottle_water`. In case you want to revert the `Required` column back to its original form I can make modifications just wanted to make sure this is what you are looking for first.

```
library(dplyr)

example.df %>%
  group_by(Year, Product_grouped) %>%
  mutate(Required = sum(Required),
         Purchased02 = if_else(Required >= Group_avail & Product == "bottle_water", 
                               Required - Group_avail, 0))

# A tibble: 9 x 7
# Groups:   Year, Product_grouped [6]
   Year Product      Product_grouped Required Group_avail Purchased Purchased02
  <int> <chr>        <chr>              <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1 bottle_water water                 25          25         0           0
2     1 tap_water    water                 25          25         0           0
3     1 juice        juice                 10          10         0           0
4     2 bottle_water water                 30          25         5           5
5     2 tap_water    water                 30          25         0           0
6     2 juice        juice                 10          10         0           0
7     3 bottle_water water                 45          25        20          20
8     3 tap_water    water                 45          25         0           0
9     3 juice        juice                  0          10         0           0
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Is there any way to make it more explicit for `bottle_water` - I'm not clear what row_number() does here, but it may be better if the function didn't rely on the order of products :)

Comment: Yes of course, I made some modifications. Please test it on your original data and let me know in what way you would like me to improve it to better suited your purpose.

Answer (score 3):

A little inelegant, but this use piping to achieve the result by splitting out bottle_water and then adding back into the dataframe.

```
temp <- example.df

temp <- temp %>% 
  group_by(Product_grouped, Year) %>% 
  filter(Product %in% c("bottle_water", "tap_water")) %>% 
  mutate(Required_grouped = sum(Required)) %>% 
  filter(Product == "bottle_water") %>% 
  mutate(Purchased = ifelse(Required_grouped - Group_avail > 0, Required_grouped - Group_avail, 0)) %>% 
  select(-"Required_grouped")
  
example.df <- example.df %>% 
  filter(Product != "bottle_water") %>% 
  bind_rows(temp) %>% 
  arrange(Year)
```

If the order is important, then set Product to a factor and add to `arrange(Year)`.